# Product of two finitely presented ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, $I,J \subseteq$ $A$ finitely presented  ideals of $A$. I am interested in the following question:

> Must $IJ$ be finitely presented as well $?$

Firstly, the product $IJ$ must be finitely generated. Also, we know that tensor product of two finitely presented modules is finitely presented in [Tag 05BS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05BS) so $I \otimes J$ is. We have a natural surjective map $I \otimes J \rightarrow IJ$, therefore it's sufficent to decide whether kernel of this map is finitely generated.

I tried to find a counterexample but failed because of lack of knowledge of non-coherent rings.